# C# How do I link a number box to a scrollbar

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I need to link two number boxes to a single Vscrollbar. The scrollbar button is in the middle and set to zero, as the scroll button moves up or down the numbers change accordingly. I need a minus sign for below zero.
TIA.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Maximum / 2;
        ChangeTextBoxValues(vScrollBar1.Maximum / 2, vScrollBar1.Value);
    }

    private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        int avg = vScrollBar1.Maximum / 2;
        ChangeTextBoxValues(avg, e.NewValue);

    }
    void ChangeTextBoxValues(int AvgValue, int NewValue)
    {
        textBox1.Text = (AvgValue - NewValue).ToString();
        textBox2.Text = (NewValue - AvgValue).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the value you can do some maths with it to populate your textboxes.

```
private void vScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = vScrollBar1.Value.ToString();
    }
```